# Performing exausting computation on Cassandra database

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I have to write an output of data analysis from `Cassandra` database. Problem setting is following:

> Database contains various log messages. Extract log messages that are of type 'message_sent' and 'message_received' and calculate the average time needed for exchanging messages". Table contains > 5000000 rows in ratio half-half (between sent and received messages).

I want to use `python` driver for working in `CQL`. Currently the script is simple but really slow (I fetch all rows of one type and for every 'message_sent I search for message received (with the same client_id and server_id), store time difference into a variable and calculate the average in the end.

I know that `Cassandra` has User Defined Functions (and UDA functions) but I failed to apply them to my problem. What I have in mind is performing a more complicated query which would collect all the data I need and I would get the output from the query itself (which would be easy in `SQL`).

What is the best way to get the effect of `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` clauses from `SQL` in `CQL`?

Comment: You probably want to use Spark if your looking to do analytics/BI, it will do everything right to optimize reads. Generally instead of asking "how do I query it" with Cassandra you should ask "how do I store it" and adjust your data model so you don't need to read the entire dataset to solve a query. By design Cassandra makes it hard to make queries that need to process the entirety of the database.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink but that begs the question of what is Cassandra good for. One of the advantages of using Cassandra is fast read performance and since (in this naive approach) I'm searching for a particular row with partitioning on the correct keys and it is stil slow. I'm using Datastax VM for these purposes and I'd like to implement a solution so that it is easily ported to other VMs, without additional setup. I feel that the problem I have to solve is solvable in `Cassandra` alone but I only need to find a way :)